# redis-cli : set value turned to (nil) automatically

Tags: redis, timeout, key, persist

I use Redis to store just one information, a token value I collect on a service. I've seen that value was automatically delete.

So I tried to create a simple key through redis-cli to check, like this:

```
SET myvar "123456789"
```

I then type

```
GET myvar
```

and it returns

```
"123456789"
```

However if I keep redis-cli open then waiting for a 5 minutes. After that if I type again:

```
GET myvar
```

the response then is

```
(nil)
```

I didn't do anything special just created the myvar key in redis. but Redis changes this value to (nil). I don't know why

In **/etc/redis/redis.conf** I've setup this mode

```
supervised systemd
```

Do you know why Redis auto NIL my content?

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to avoid the issue by [uninstalling redis](http://grainier.net/how-to-uninstall-redis-server-from-ubuntu/) since I've used **make** to install it. Then I've re-installed by using

```
sudo apt install redis-server
```

And it fixed the issue!!!

I was using this method for installing Redis, and there was an issue with it , for me

```
cd /tmp
curl -O http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xzvf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make
make test
sudo make install
sudo mkdir /etc/redis
sudo cp /tmp/redis-stable/redis.conf /etc/redis
```

I don't know why, but this way of installation was buggy.